# self dual boolean function

Tags: boolean-algebra

How many self-dual Boolean functions of n variables are there?Please help me how to calculate such like problems.

> A Boolean function $f_1^D$ is said to be the dual of another Boolean function $f_1$ if $f_1^D$ is obtained from $f_1$ by interchanging the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ and the constants $0$ and $1$. For example, if $f_1(a,b,c)=(a+b)\cdot(b+c)$ then $f_1^D(a,b,c)=a\cdot{b}+b\cdot{c}$.
>
> A Boolean function $f$ is self-dual if $f_1=f_1^D$. Given $f_1(a,b,c)=a\bar{b}+\bar{b}c+x$, find the Boolean expression $x$ such that $f_1$ is self-dual.

How to calculate this value?Please help me.

Comment: Just expand the definition and try to solve boolean equation: $a\bar{b} + \bar{b}c + x = (a\bar{b} + \bar{b}c + x)^D = (a + \bar{b})(\bar{b} + c)x^D$.

Comment: plz give me the detail solution

Comment: 333rd view for this thread! Anyway, what have you tried?

Comment: In my opinion it woulb be usefull:
http://hal.upmc.fr/docs/00/78/63/36/PDF/formallysdbf.pdf

Comment: Meanwhile, a similar question has been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602598/number-of-self-dual-functions-and-number-of-inputs-for-which-self-dual-function/1602660#1602660).

Comment: Functions don't have operators.  Expressions have operators.  Functions are limited by the number of variables involved, functions can have an infinite number of expressions, and expressions are not limited by the number of variables involved.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, we'll start with expanding the definition (I'll write $x'$ instead of $\overline{x}$):

$\begin{align*}
ab' + b'c + x &= (ab' + b'c + x)^D \\
&= (a + b')(b' + c)x^D \\
&= (ac + b')x^D
\end{align*}$

where $x(a, b, c)$.

Let's decompose $x$ wrto $b$: $x(a, b, c) = by(a, c) + b'z(a, c)$, so $x^D = (b + y^D)(b' + z^D)$.

We have equivalent equation $ab' + b'c + by + b'z = (ac + b')(b + y^D)(b' + z^D) = (b' + acz^D)(b + y^D) = abcz^D + b'y^D + acy^Dz^D$.

Case $b = 1$ gives $y = acz^D$.

Case $b = 0$ gives $a + c + z = y^D$ which is equivalent to the first case. So we have a necessary condition.

Now take any boolean function $z(a,c)$ so $y = acz^D$ and $x = abcz^D + b'z$.

Then LHS: $ab' + b'c + abcz^D + b'z$,

RHS: $abcz^D + b'(a + c + z) + ac(a + c + z)z^D = abcz^D + ab' + b'c + b'z + acz^D$ = LHS.

So it is also suffitient condition.

So $\{abcz^D + b'z: z(a, c)\}$ are all solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of self dual functions possible with $n$ variables is $2^m$, where $m=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Its $2^{2^{n-1}}$.